# Custom postion for v-dialog Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I need to open a v-dialog of certain width and height on right bottom side of my page, but, I can't understand how to do.
V-dialog always are centered on the page, I searched on official doc, tried use CSS, but wasn't able
any ideas?

Comment: Share the initial code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 13):

**Note**: Other provided solutions are not satisfying because they mess up transitions, or we can't use scoped-styles, or they suggest using `!important` etc.

#### Solution

Add arbitrary `content-class` class to your dialog:

```
<v-dialog content-class="my-custom-dialog">
```

Then we can use scoped styles:

```
<style scoped>
  >>> .my-custom-dialog {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

May I ask what the >>> means?
Why do you use `conetent-class` instead of `class`?

Comment: @user2495085 `>>>` are `deep selectors` (read about them here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors). We use `content-class` instead of `class` so that our style is properly attached to dialog because that is how `v-dialog` component works (read more about it here, and check the linked docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720069/how-to-add-a-class-with-new-styles-css-to-v-dialog-vuetify)

Comment: Thank you Traxo, really appreciate your explaination!

Comment: I wanted to use `lang='scss'` but it did not work! so `>>>` seems to work in plain css mode!!

Comment: @PouyaM in scss I think you can use `/deep/` instead of `>>>`. You can try it out or read the docs for scss deep selectors.

Comment: need to add a selector before the `>>>` i.e. `.v-dialog >>> '.my-custom-dialog {...}`

Answer (score 8):

[This feature is being looked at](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4807) but for now you can use edit the CSS class yourself. For instance, to get it to display in the bottom right use:

```
.v-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;"
```

On the first v-card inside the v-dialog

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your styles:

```
.v-dialog:not(.v-dialog--fullscreen) {
    bottom: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone new coming to this post, its worth checking out `VBottomSheet` for this functionality.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/bottom-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Came to this page looking for answers but none of the above suggestions worked for me with Vuetiful 2.2.11. Ended up doing this:

```
.v-dialog__content {
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue 3 and Vuetify 3.0 alpha this solution allows to use the dialog with current mouse position. **v-dialog** is inside the **v-overlay-container** which is outside the **v-app** element hierarchy so the global CSS file must be used. In Vuetify 2.x **v-overlay-container** is inside the **v-app** hierarchy.
I guess a solution with **scoped CSS** and usage of **deep()** is possible in this case.
CSS variables are defined and a rule for **v-overlay__content** which is responsible for the position is added :

```
:root {
    --dialog-xpos: 22px;
    --dialog-ypos: 55px;
}
.v-overlay__content {
    top: var(--dialog-ypos);
    left: var(--dialog-xpos);
}
```

The click event handler modifies the variables before dialog activation :

```
function onClick(ev: MouseEvent) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dialog-xpos', ev.clientX.toString() + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dialog-ypos', ev.clientY.toString() + 'px');
    showDialog.value = true;
}
```