# Login dialog cliped under toolbar in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to have some dialog/panel to place my login form. There will be login button in top toolbar and on click some type of non-modal dialog will pop-up below the toolbar containing login form and register link. Something like the real Google contats do for login.

But I don't have any idea how to clip/show the some panel under the toolbar. I even don't know which one to use should it be v-dialog? I should look somehing like below. I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415763/2944265) where they just position it manually, but anyway it is still modal even if I will get the CSS positioning right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I should use v-menu with slot="activator" like in this example

```html
<template>
  <v-layout row>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
      <v-card height="200px">
        <v-card-title class="blue white--text">
          <span class="headline">Menu</span>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-menu bottom left>
            <v-btn
              slot="activator"
              dark
              icon
            >
              <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

            <v-list>
              <v-list-tile
                v-for="(item, i) in items"
                :key="i"
                @click=""
              >
                <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>Lorem Ipsum</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```