# How to add a class with new styles CSS to v-dialog?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am working with Vuetify, using the following `v-dialog` in a component:

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <!--Indicador-->
      <v-dialog class="vdialognew" v-model="mostrarIndicator" persistent>
         <v-content>
            <v-container fluid fill-height>
               <v-layout align-center justify-center>
                  <cube-shadow class="spinnerRotate"></cube-shadow>
               </v-layout>
            </v-container>
         </v-content>
      </v-dialog>
      <!-------------->
   </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
   .vdialognew {
   box-shadow: none !important;
   max-width: 610px !important;
   }
</style>
```

As you will see in `v-dialog` I have added the `vdialognew` class to apply those new styles, but when loading the content by checking in the browser console, I see that `vdialognew` does not apply to it, only. Similarly, if I use the style property inside the `v-dialog` tag, it does not work for me. How can I make such a change?

I am doing this modification to eliminate the box that is seen behind the green square:

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Passing `class` to the v-dialog **won't work**, use `content-class` instead:

```html
<v-dialog content-class="vdialognew" v-model="mostrarIndicator" persistent>
```

Have a look at the [v-dialog docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/dialogs)

Comment: Just checked in dev mode - works fine. Could you show your code?

Comment: does anyone find that every time you open a dialog it creates and new one on the dom and doesn't remove the previous version?

Comment: then how do you set a `style` on it

Answer (score 4):

Use "content-class" is the correct answer as mentioned by @mxmass, but if you're trying to add the class in scoped level, it won't work.

Add the style in the beginning, so let's say if you're using nuxt, create a main styling file such as main.scss, then in nuxt.config.js, add that file in css section. That way, your styling class is available when you're using "content-class". Hope this helps.

Comment: I was in the same boat and wondering why my class styles are ignored. Thanks.

Comment: You can wrap your dialog with a `div` element and then attach your dialog to that div, e.g. `<div class="dialog-wrapper"><v-dialog attach=".dialog-wrapper">...</div>` for scoped style to work.

Answer (score -6):

you can add multiple names to class

```
<v-dialog class="vdialognew dialogCss"></v-dialog>

<style>
.dialogCss {
background: #8e5ba6;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The change does not apply, it is the inconvenience that I have.