How to adjust the position of v-dialog which opens on click of a button vuetify vuejs?
I'm trying to create a popup using v-dialog vuetify on click of Open dialog button. I want the popup to appear just below the button. Something similar to the below image.

Here's the code. I tried using position to change the position, But it doesn't work as expected.
<template lang="">
  <v-dialog>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props: activatorProps }">
      <v-btn
        block
        color="black"
        rounded="2"
        v-bind="activatorProps"
        text="Open popup"
        variant="flat"
        style="z-index: 10"
      ></v-btn>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:default="{ isActive }">
      <v-card class="border-thin w-50 change-position" style="z-index: 9">
        <v-table density="compact" class="border-thin" fixed-header>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <!--- content of head ------->
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!--- content of tbody------->
          </tbody>
        </v-table>
        <v-divider></v-divider>    
      </v-card>
    </template>
  </v-dialog>

</template>

<style scoped>
/* .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody {
  border-bottom: thin solid grey !important;
} */

:deep() .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: thin solid rgba(var(--v-border-color), var(--v-border-opacity));
}
:deep() .v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td:not(:last-child),
.v-table .v-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr > th:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: thin solid rgba(var(--v-border-color), var(--v-border-opacity));
}

.change-position {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 1px;
}
</style>

How to fix this?

Could you use v-menu instead and specify the location as bottom?

@Grant I ended up using v-menu. But I want to know if the position of dialog can be adjusted.

Check the answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415502/custom-postion-for-v-dialog-vuetify

To rewrite some styles, it is better to use CSS modules, that is, change scoped to module. And then fix it .v-overload__content on top of the parent.
<style module> 
  .v-overlay__content {
     top: 20px !important;  
  }
</style>

